# EXC BAD ACCESS TREAD in c

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

it gives me  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc) at the strcmp in the while (strcmp(parola, temp->next->parola) [picture of the xcode debugging session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDOz1.png)

```
if (temp->next != NULL){
        if (strcmp(temp->next->parola, "\0") != 0 && strcmp(parola, "\0") != 0){
            while (strcmp(parola, temp->next->parola) != 0){
                if(temp->next != NULL){
                    if (strcmp(temp->next->parola, "\0") != 0 && strcmp(parola, "\0") != 0){
                        temp = temp->next;
                    } else {break;}
                } else {break;}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is using `temp->next->parola` before checking that `temp->next` is not NULL, so I expect that `temp->next` is NULL when the error occurs.

Comment: yeah but the xcode debugger says it's not null, also it should throw th error when i try to access temp->next in the if statement, not in the while

Comment: Inside the `while` loop, the code sets `temp = temp->next` and then does `strcmp(parola, temp->next->parola)` without checking whether `temp->next` is NULL.

Comment: don't i check it in the if (temp->next != NULL){}else {break}?

Comment: The condition in the `while` is checked, then the `if` inside the loop checks for NULL, then `temp = temp->next` is executed, and that sequence repeats. So `temp = temp->next` is followed by the `strcmp(parola, temp->next->parola` without first checking that `temp->next != NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (temp->next != NULL){
    if (strcmp(temp->next->parola, "\0") != 0 && strcmp(parola, "\0") != 0){
        while (strcmp(parola, temp->next->parola) != 0){
                    if (strcmp(temp->next->parola, "\0") != 0 && strcmp(parola, "\0") != 0){
                        temp = temp->next;
                if(temp->next != NULL){
                    } else {break;}
                } else {break;}
            }
        }
}
```